# Apache nutch crawler with MongoDB is not fetching correct URLs

Tags: nutch

I have installed Apache Nutch on my CentOS 6.7 VM and configured it to save the output in to MongoDB.

However the problem is that its is not crawling the correct URL or it is not returning correct URLs. Do you think this could be because of the security of the website.

My conf/regex-urlfilter.txt has following entry:

```
# accept anything else
+^http://*.*
```

seed.txt (just for testing purpose) has

```
[abc@X.X.X.X local]$ cat urls/seed.txt
http://www.sears.com/
```

The steps I am following are Inject-->generate-->fetch-->parse-->updatedb

```
[abc@X.X.X.X local]$ bin/nutch inject urls/
InjectorJob: starting at 2017-05-23 18:26:08
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore as the Gora storage class.
InjectorJob: total number of urls rejected by filters: 0
InjectorJob: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 1
Injector: finished at 2017-05-23 18:26:11, elapsed: 00:00:02
[abc@X.X.X.X local]$ bin/nutch generate -topN 80
GeneratorJob: starting at 2017-05-23 18:26:17
GeneratorJob: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
GeneratorJob: starting
GeneratorJob: filtering: true
GeneratorJob: normalizing: true
GeneratorJob: topN: 80
GeneratorJob: finished at 2017-05-23 18:26:21, time elapsed: 00:00:03
GeneratorJob: generated batch id: 1495581977-876634391 containing 1 URLs
[abc@X.X.X.X local]$ bin/nutch fetch -all
FetcherJob: starting at 2017-05-23 18:26:32
FetcherJob: fetching all
FetcherJob: threads: 10
FetcherJob: parsing: false
FetcherJob: resuming: false
FetcherJob : timelimit set for : -1
Using queue mode : byHost
Fetcher: threads: 10
fetching https://www.facebook.com/LinioEcuador/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://www.clubpremier.com/mx/conocenos/niveles/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://twitter.com/LinioEcuador/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://www.instagram.com/clubpremier/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://reservaciones.clubpremier.com/profiles/itineraries.cfm (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://s3.amazonaws.com/club_premier/logo-cp.svg (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1
Fetcher: throughput threshold sequence: 5
QueueFeeder finished: total 49 records. Hit by time limit :0
fetching https://www.facebook.com/clubpremiermexico (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://s3.amazonaws.com/club_premier/clubpremier-components-info/images/logo-cp.svg (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://twitter.com/clubpremier_mx (queue crawl delay=1000ms)
10/10 spinwaiting/active, 4 pages, 0 errors, 0.8 1 pages/s, 1151 1151 kb/s, 40 URLs in 2 queues
fetching https://www.clubpremier.com/mx/acumula/compra/multiplica-puntos-premier (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
fetching https://reservaciones.clubpremier.com/travel/arc.cfm (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
10/10 spinwaiting/active, 6 pages, 0 errors, 0.6 0 pages/s, 798 445 kb/s, 38 URLs in 1 queues
fetching https://www.clubpremier.com/mx/acumula/compra/adquiere-puntos-premier/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
10/10 spinwaiting/active, 7 pages, 0 errors, 0.5 0 pages/s, 606 223 kb/s, 37 URLs in 1 queues
fetching https://www.clubpremier.com/mx/acumula/aerolineas/skyteam/ (queue crawl delay=5000ms)
```

You can see above the urls generated are not at all related to the website I want to crawl. Please help me fix this.

Thanks,
Shilpa

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the URL filter is configured to accept every page in the www. If the intention is to limit the crawl to pages in the domain sears.com, the rules may look like

```
# allow pages in the domain sears.com
+^https?://([a-z0-9]+\.)*sears\.com
# skip anything else
-.*
```

Also have a look at the following configuration properties:

```
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, outlinks leading from a page to external hosts or domain
  will be ignored. This is an effective way to limit the crawl to include
  only initially injected hosts, without creating complex URLFilters.
  See 'db.ignore.external.links.mode'.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links.mode</name>
  <value>byHost</value>
  <description>Alternative value is byDomain</description>
</property>
```